# Transfer more than 8 bytes using can-bus on embedded Linux

Tags: embedded-linux, can-bus

I have a node on a can-bus that will send out ~1KB data to the other nodes on the can-bus. With the max payload being 8 bytes using CAN protocol what options are available for sending larger amounts without having to write my own custom transmit and receive functions to fragment the data? The nodes are running embedded Linux.

I have very little experience with CAN.

Comment: This would have to be done on the application layer protocol. You can check out for example the CANopen SDO protocol for inspiration, but it should be noted that CAN is not ideal if you need to send that much data.

Comment: The de-facto standard for this would be ISO 15765-2. However, you should really re-think whether the CAN bus is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Protocols on top of CAN such as J1939, NMEA2000 and CANopen provide their own ways to do this. So I would say: Find a software stack for another protocol on top of CAN. thanks.